# git config changes email and username but commit and pushes done via previous user

Tags: git

I changed my git config user.name and user.email using the command git config --global user.name *name*. When I run git config --global --list in terminal or in command prompt, I get my credentials. But when I push or commit, the commit/push goes from previous user.
What should I do?
Right now I am doing commit/pushes from github desktop.

Comment: Identity you use to commit (from git config and that could be overridden in some repositories) is something different than credentials that you use to push (from credential stored).

Comment: I fixed it. Read the answer down below

Answer (score -1, accepted):

So basically, windows credentials cached git credentials. So, I went to control panel > credential manager > windows credential.
There you will be seeing git:github.com or something similar. Check if it's your account. If it's not, then edit it or remove it(in my case I edited).

Answer (score 1):

Git also has a config for each repository. Try going to your repo (with your command line tool) and change the config without the `--global` argument.

Answer (score 1):

Changing `user.email` in your configuration will change the email in the commits you create from now on, but does not change the author of already existing commits.

If you want to modify the author of your previous commits: you will have to rewrite them.

See for example this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/1320317/86072

Comment: actually I fixed it, I will share my answer.